# Can't Get Shared Preference Value Even Though Values Exist

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

Any time I try to `getInt()` from a `SharedPreference` my app crashes, yet I can iterate through the preferences as a map. For instance, see the starred lines below:

```
private void loadPref(){
    myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int sf = DEFAULT_VALUE;

    Map<String,?> keys = myPrefs.getAll();
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
        if (entry.getKey().contentEquals("score_format"))
            // this works:                                         //*****
            sf = Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().toString());    //*****
    }

    // but this does not:                                          //*****  
    // sf = myPrefs.getInt("score_format", DEFAULT_VALUE);         //*****
    setScoreFormat(sf);
}
```

Clearly, my prefs are being saved (as evidenced by this sample and working preference screens across multiple activities). I am calling super.onCreate() before trying to access getDefaultSharedPreferences.

What should I be considering to understand why this code is not working? Why would the map work but not the "getInt" method? I did notice that the app would also crash if I tried to cast the key value explicitly... I had to cast it toString first.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the logcat of the exception? and the definition of `DEFAULT_VALUE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to parse, make sure the score you're putting into the intent with `putExtra` is an int type, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like object assosiated with `score_format` key is a `String` but you are trying to obtain it as `int` which is a mistake.

Comment: Yes, quite right. Can't believe I missed that. Darned trees were everywhere and I couldn't see the forest. Thanks!